# Can't connect to webserver mysql with Python, but it's works fine in Php

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my webserver MySQL (my domain MySQL server) with Python but I keep getting this error:
**2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='myuser', password='mypass',
                            host='myhost',
                            database='mydb',
                            connect_timeout=10000)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
         print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
         print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cnx.close()
```

Result: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

**Connecting to this mysql server works fine in PHP.**
Also connnecting to localhost MySQL (XAMPP) server works with Python too.

Any idea why I keep getting this error when im trying to connect with Python to webserver MySQL database?

Comment: where/when do you get this error? please note that and `else` block on try/except runs if the exception did NOT occur, so if you connected successfully then connection will then be closed

Comment: what is "webserver mysql" and what is "localhost mysql"... are you trying on some remote application server like wamp?

Comment: localhost mysql -> I mean Xampp server AND

webserver mysql -> My Mysql server for my domain

Comment: Nullman: This error is catched by except

Comment: do you have any sort of proxy?

Comment: Nullman: I'm connecting wihout proxy

Comment: unrelated but if you reply to people, make sure to write  at at sign (@) before their name or they wont get a notification @ViktorKelemen

Comment: what port are you using for connect to mysql ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar it's the default 3306
(Thanks Nullman)

Comment: @ViktorKelemen have you tried to change value time out in your my.cnf  (server mysql)???

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I can not access my my.cnf file, I could contact with my server admins, but since in PHP it's works fine I assumed it cant be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed, it turns out the database hosting got bad settings, so for some reason they did not receive my calls. It has been fixed by switching to a new host.